# docker status "Restating" forever

Tags: docker

I created some containers and they are not ready to use, always "restarting" status:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                        NAMES
02141a219070        debian              "/bin/bash"         53 minutes ago      Restarting (0) 3 minutes ago                                 test
3a8b684011d4        debian              "/bin/bash"         About an hour ago   Restarting (0) 4 minutes ago    10.140.10.151:443->443/tcp   support-web.equifax.ru
ad40188569cd        debian              "/bin/bash"         4 hours ago         Restarting (0) 25 minutes ago   10.140.10.150:443->443/tcp   vpn.equifax.ru
```

No exec:

**docker exec test /bin/bash**

Error response from daemon: Container test is restarting, wait until the container is running

No logs:

**docker logs test**

I have created the container this way:

**docker run --name=test --restart=always  debian /bin/bash**

How to troubleshoot Docker?

Comment: Please include how you run the image and is it the `debian` base image

Comment: You need to run /bin/bash interactively. Otherwise, it will exit and restart forever.

Answer (score 8):

You need run it interactively.

```
docker run -ti --name=test --restart=always debian /bin/bash
```

#### Explanation

```
   -t, --tty=false                 Allocate a pseudo-TTY
   -i, --interactive=false         Keep STDIN open even if not attached
```

Comment: How do you add this to a docker compose file?